# Combining columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script with an output of multiple columns which are put beneath each other. I would like the columns to be merged together and to drop the duplicates. I've tried merge, combine, concatenate and joining, but I can't seem to figure it out. I also tried to merge as a list, but that doesn't seem to help as well. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.ExcelFile('path')
newlist = [x for x in data.sheet_names if x.startswith("ZZZ")]

for x in newlist:
    sheets = pd.read_excel(data, sheetname = x)
    column = sheets.loc[:,'YYY']
```

Any help is really appreciated!

**Edit**

Some more info about the code: *data* is where an excelfile is loaded. Then at *newlist*, the sheetnames that start with ZZZ are shown. Then in the for-loop, these sheets are called. At *column*, the columns named YYY are called. These columns are put beneath each other, but aren't merged yet. For example:
[Here is the output of the columns now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUvLc.png) and I would like them to be one list from 1 to 17.

I hope it is more clear now!

**Edit 2.0**

Here I tried the concat method that is mentioned below. However, I still get the output as the picture above shows instead of a list from 1 to 17.

```
my_concat_series = pd.Series()
for x in newlist:
    sheets = pd.read_excel(data, sheetname = x)
    column = sheets.loc[:,'YYY']
    my_concat_series = pd.concat([my_concat_series,column]).drop_duplicates()
    print(my_concat_series)
```

Comment: How do you expect any help without showing us what your data looks like?

Comment: When you say "I would like the columns to be merged together" could you put an example please? It's hard to know how we can solve this as it's quite unclear.

Comment: Yes, sorry, will do. I'll edit the question!

Comment: We need an example of your dataframe before the operation of merging, and the corresponding desired output. This will help to answer.

Comment: I have put a picture in the question with the output of the code. Is this helpful like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how `pandas.concat` doesn't work, let's try an example corresponding to the data picture you posted:

```
import pandas as pd
col1 = pd.Series(np.arange(1,12))
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9     10
10    11
dtype: int64

col2 = pd.Series(np.arange(7,18))
0      7
1      8
2      9
3     10
4     11
5     12
6     13
7     14
8     15
9     16
10    17
dtype: int64
```

And then use `pd.concat` and `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([col1,col2]).drop_duplicates()

0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9     10
10    11
5     12
6     13
7     14
8     15
9     16
10    17
dtype: int64
```

You can then reshape your data the way you want them, for instance if you don't want a duplicate index:
`pd.concat([col1,col2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)`,

or if you want the values as a numpy array instead of a pandas series:

`pd.concat([col1,col2]).drop_duplicates()`

Note that in the last case you can also use `numpy` arrays from the begginning, which is faster:

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(np.concatenate((col1.values,col2.values)))
```

If you want them as a list:

`list(pd.concat([col1,col2]).drop_duplicates())`

Comment: I've tried that, but the problem is that I don't have two separate columns like col1 and col2. I have a for loop that puts all the columns behind each other without separate names, so I can't call them column by column. So I think I'll have to do something with append in the for-loop maybe?

Comment: In the for loop do you have a temporary name for the column that is processed? If so, you can use this `temp` name to concat it to the previous Series using this in the for-loop: `my_concat_series = pd.concat([my_concat_series,temp]).drop_duplicates()` with an initiation as an empty series: `my_concat_series = pd.Series()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did this:
`my_concat_series = pd.Series()`
`for x in newlist:`
    `sheets = pd.read_excel(data, sheetname = x)`
    `column = sheets.loc[:,'YYY']`
    `my_concat_series = pd.concat([my_concat_series,theta]).drop_duplicates()`
    
But the columns are still not merged. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add that to your question and post a picture of your output so we could compare it to the desired output please? That would help clarify things.

Comment: I edited the question! The output is still the same as the picture in the first edit:(